# How to Wait All Nested Loop Axios Complete (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, axios

i'm new to Node js and axios, with my previous experience in vanilla javascript. i encountered a problem of how to wait all of my nested-loop axios code to complete to get the final array of object **_FileData **

```
var _objFile = new Object();
var _FileData = [];

BrowseProjectBIMDocs();

//Project Directory
function BrowseProjectBIMDocs() {

        var config = {
            ...
        };
        axios.request(config)
            .then((response) => {
                for (var i = 0; i < response.data.data.length; i++) {
                    BrowseFilesBIMDocs(response.data.data[i]);
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });

//Folder Directory
function BrowseFilesBIMDocs(ProjectData) {

        var config = {
            ...
        };

        axios.request(config)
            .then((response) => {

                if (response.data.data.length > 0) {

                    for (var i = 0; i < response.data.data.length; i++) {

                        if (response.data.data[i].type == 'folders') {

                            //Recursive
                            BrowseFilesBIMDocs(response.data.data[i]);
                        }
                        else {
                            GetBIMDocsFileAttributes(response.data.data[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }


//File Attribute
function GetBIMDocsFileAttributes(FileData) {

        var config = {
          ...
        };

        axios.request(config)
            .then((response) => {
                for (var i = 0; i < response.data.included.length; i++) {

                    _objFile = {}
                    _objFile.FileID = response.data.included[i].id
                    _objFile.FileName = response.data.included[i].attributes.displayName
                    _objFile.FileURL = response.data.included[i].links.webView.href
                    _objFile.FileType = response.data.included[i].attributes.fileType

                    _FileData.push(_objFile);
                }

            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

//how and where should i write the code **console.log(_FileData)** ?
```

how and where should i write the code **console.log(_FileData)** so it printed only once where all of my nested axios calls is completed?

i already tried to use combination of Return Axios,Promise.All, and Await, but it doesn't seems to work because of my lack of ES6 Practical Knoweldge.
Thanks before, and sorry for the bad grammar :)

Edit : Currently i'm using Timeout function as temporary solution since it's a background services that run once a day, but i know it's not the best practice

```
//how and where should i write the code **console.log(_FileData)** ?

 setTimeout(() => {
   console.log(_FileData);
   connection.close();
}, 10000)
```